# Copying objects to new S3 folder, but only from certain folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy a bunch of PDFs from folders in my S3 bucket, the folders in question are a number of folders like DD.MM.YYYY, into a folder called "Archive". The question is, how do I isolate my copy request to only grab PDF's from folders in the bucket with the DD/MM/YYYY naming structure?

Here is the rake task I built. However I'm receiving a "Don't know how to build this task" error.

```
namespace :courts do
  task update_ocr_documents: :environment do
    OcrDocument.find_each do |ocr_document|
      ::Courts::Operations::OcrDocuments::RecognizeExisting.run(id: ocr_document.id, skip_auth: true)
    end
  end

  task sync_ocr_bucket: :environment do
    ::Courts::SyncronizeBucketJob.perform_now
  end

  task move_old_documents: :environment do
    bucket = Settings.file_storage.ocr_documents.s3_credentials.bucket
    file_util = Courts::Aws::FileUtil.new(bucket) # Should be called S3Util ?
    file_util.get_objects { |obj| obj.key.ends_with?('.pdf') } # 
     TODO: get only pdf files that are in the folders with names dd.mm.yyy }
    file_util.move_objects('archive')
  end
end
```

Comment: `Don't know how to build this task` means the task is not being called correctly, not that there's an error in the code.

Comment: @dbugger the command is rake move_old_documents no?

Comment: Depends on the name space of the rake file, which you have not provided

Comment: @dbugger the namespace is courts, I've attached the full rakefile.

Comment: if you replace the everything in the method with `puts "Rake task called"`, can you call it successfully?

Comment: @dbugger No, receiving the same 'Don't know how to build task 'update_ocr_documents' error.

Comment: That was not the task you were asking about. slim down your rake file to one task with nothing in it.  make sure you can call it.  If you can't, there is something not set up properly with your project.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I solved the issue by using rake courts:update_ocr_documents , I don't suppose you have an idea for the best way to accomplish said rake task ? The code is not working